# Basic C programming exercise stuck

Tags: c

I have been doing A LOT of exercises and examples to get the hang of C, its finally starting to sink in slowly, but surely.  Though I'm having one small problem with this and can't amend it for the life of me:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR * argv[]) {
    int i, grades[] = {98, 87, 92, 79, 85};
    for(i = 0; i <= 4; ++i) {
        printf("Element %d is %d\n"
        i, grades[i]);
    }
    i = getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is the **i** it is expecting a bracket, I don't know why and any amendment I have tried has failed, I know its a simple problem but it has me stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are missing a comma before `i`.

Comment: Please post these kind of questions to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) next time.

Comment: @Rapptz: That's IMHO really not helpful in this case! OP needs to learn to spot such simple mistakes in his own style.

Comment: @DanielFrey His own style had a 1-liner printf and when my tool fixed it, it put it in an extra line because of the lack of comma. So I fixed that part again manually, however Chad reverted it back to my fix. So I don't know what you mean. :)

Comment: @DrummerB Technically, this question would be off-topic on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq?mnu=1#questions) also.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're missing a comma that separates arguments in your call to `printf`:

```
printf("Element %d is %d\n", i, grades[i]);
//                         ^
//                      This one
```

Comment: Sorry that this is in the wrong section, will know for next time and I do usually see my own mistakes though could not this time though getting something so remedial pointed out is a good way to keep it stuck in my head, thank you and sorry